# docker-compose not picking updated code

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

Iam new to docker-compose trying to run a sample script in a container.
Below is my Dockerfile.

```
#Dockerfile
FROM debian
ADD . /scripts
CMD ["bash", "/scripts/count.sh"]

#docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  count:
    build: .
    volumes:
     - .:/scripts
```

Sample bash script which runs in the container

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
#while [[ $count -le 30 ]];
while :
do
#(( count++ ))
echo "hello world"
done
```

when i run the docker-compose up , it runs well and i can see the logs as "hello world". Since I have exported volumes on the host to the container if i change the script uncomment the line

```
while [[ $count -le 30 ]];
```

I cannot see the container stopping at count 30 or if i change "hello world" to any text it doesnt pick the code.
I have mounted my local /tmp/scripts to /scripts into container
Am I missing something?

I worked with the example in the [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-update-the-application), it worked and i get the updated code.
But it doesnt work with my example.
please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restart the process; bash doesn't detect changes in your file and reload it automatically.

It is the same as the following:

1. Open a terminal on your computer, and type `/bin/bash /scripts/count.sh`
2. Open another terminal session, and then edit `count.sh`, then save it.

Now you don't expect the first window to automatically pick up the changes do you? The exact same process is happening in the container. To get the first window to reflect the changes in `count.sh`, you need to relaunch it.

Mounting a volume just means that file changes are visible in the container, it doesn't have an impact on whatever process is using those files.

The reason it works in the docker-compose example is because they are using Flask as an example app. If you run Flask in debug mode, it will automatically reload when it detects any change to the file, from the [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#debug-mode) (with my emphasis):

> The flask script is nice to start a local development server, but you
>   would have to restart it manually after each change to your code. That
>   is not very nice and Flask can do better. **If you enable debug support
>   the server will reload itself on code changes**, and it will also
>   provide you with a helpful debugger if things go wrong.

The automatic reload is feature of flask, and not of docker compose.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the build without cache.

```
docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up
```